# FCM Web Notification Token

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement FCM Web Notification using [fcm-notification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-notification). I am struck with creating with my web token on my front end. I don't how to create a token in my front. I wrote NodeJS code.

**Code**

```
var fcm = require('fcm-notification');
var FCM = new fcm('../../web-notification-6dcb6-firebase-adminsdk-j7hx8-c76a6601dd.json');
var token = 'token here';

var message = {
    webpush: {
      notification: {
        title: '$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
        body: '$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.',
        icon: 'https://my-server/icon.png'
      }
    },
    topic: 'TopicName'
  };

FCM.send(message, function(err, response) {
    if(err){
        console.log('error found', err);
    }else {
        console.log('response here', response);
    }
})
```

What is token here? How to generate it from my Angular? Is there is any other way to do it?

Comment: You want it in angular or want help in node.

Comment: Send token from Angular to node and node use the token to send the notification back to Angular and Angular consumes the notification